# Custom JavaScript list button is not visible

Tags: list-button

I have a custom object. There I'm trying to add list button of content source JavaScript. The script is correct, I've copied it from existing functional script. However, I'm not able to see the button in any section (Button/ QuickAction/ Mobile and lightning action) of page layout to add it in the quick panel.

What could be the issue? The old list button was created in 2016. Does salesforce has stopped supporting JavaScript List buttons now? If yes than what is the alternate of it (is it creating LWC and add it in button action)

Kindly suggest,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tags aren't bits of text that you add randomly. They're supposed to describe what the question is about. This isn't about SalesforceDX (it appears none of your questions are), the cli, apex, etc... So it's not appropriate to be using those tags.

Comment: Check this may help you - [Add, remove, or create buttons for a list view](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386168&type=1)

Answer (score 0):

Custom JavaScript buttons and links only work in Classic. You'll need to make a Lightning alternative in order to enable custom code for Lightning. For the most part, this means you'll be creating Lightning Web Components. For more information, please read about how to [Convert JavaScript Buttons and Links into Lightning Experience Alternatives](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lcc_javascript_buttons_overview.htm&type=5).